# What is the difference between $\det(zI - A)$ and $\det(A - zI)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-polynomial

When computing the characteristic polynomial of matrix $A$, is it the case that $$\det(zI - A) = \det(A - zI)$$ and that one should choose the construction that is best on a case-by-case basis? If so, is one of these preferred over the other? If they are not equal, which one represents the characteristic polynomial of matrix $A$?

Comment: $$\operatorname{det}(zI-A)=\operatorname{det}(-(A-zI))=(-1)^n\operatorname{det}(A-zI)$$where $A$ and $I$ are matrices of dimension $n\times n$. By convention, I generally define the monic characteristic polynomial as the characteristic polynomial, but it doesn't matter.

Comment: Since $A-zI = -(zI-A)$, if $A$ is $n\times n$ then $\det(zI-A) = (-1)^n\det(A-zI)$. So they are equal if and only if $n$ is even. Since the characteristic polynomial is used mainly in order to finds its roots, both have the same roots so the difference is immaterial. Generally, when doing things by hand, $A-zI$ involves fewer modifications to $A$, so a lower chance of transcription errors. $\det(zI-A)$ is always monic (which some people want their characteristic polynomials to be), while $\det(A-zI)$ has leading coefficient $(-1)^n$.

Comment: Thank you both. That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question (with reference to the great comments that were left):

It is the case that $\det(zI - A)$ is not necessarily equal to $\det(A - zI)$. Specifically, one can obtain matrix $A - zI$ from matrix $zI - A$ by pulling a factor of $-1$ out of each row of matrix $zI - A$. Therefore, $\det(zI - A) = (-1)^n \det (A - zI)$. As a result, when $n$ is odd, $\det(zI - A) \neq \det(A - zI)$.

To determine which form correctly represents the characteristic polynomial of $A$, consider that $\det(A - zI) = (\lambda_1 - z)\cdots(\lambda_n - z)$ where $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, repeated per their algebraic multiplicities. Hence, you can see that the leading term of $\det(A - zI)$ will be $(-1)^n z^n$, which will be negative if $n$ is odd. So, the form $\det(A - zI)$ will not produce a *monic* polynomial when $n$ is odd, and therefore, $\det(A - zI)$ should not be used to represent the characteristic polynomial. By contrast, $\det(zI - A) = (z - \lambda_1) \cdots (z - \lambda_n)$ so that the leading term is $z^n$, and the polynomial produced from $\det(zI - A)$ is monic, and therefore $\det(zI - a)$ correctly represents the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

All that said, the most common use of the characteristic polynomial is to find the eigenvalues of $A$. And for this application, recognize that the roots of $\det(zI - A)$ are the same as the roots of $\det(A - zI)$, these roots being the eigenvalues of $A$. Therefore, when computing the eigenvalues of $A$, the equation $\det(A - \lambda I) = 0$ will produce the same eigenvalues as the equation $\det(\lambda I - A) = 0$. Moreover, when computing these eigenvalues by hand, the matrix $A - \lambda I$ requires fewer modifications to the original matrix $A$, and therefore is less likely to result in bookkeeping errors (i.e. dropping a minus sign). So, the equation $\det(A - \lambda I) = 0$ is actually preferred when doing hand computations.

To summarize, you will often see $\det(A - \lambda I) = 0$ used for computing eigenvalues. But if you want to correctly represent the characteristic polynomial, you should write $\det(zI - A)$.

Comment: Note that not everyone defines the characteristic polynomial to be *monic*. All your comments about "correctly representing" the characteristic polynomial, or what "should" or "should not" be used to represent the characteristic polynomial are predicated on the assumption that the characteristic polynomial *must* be monic. That is simply not true, and depends on your definitional preference. This is not a matter of "correct" and "incorrect", but of pure and simple convention.